# Error while reading file

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

When I reading file like this

```
var fciNewFileFromComputer = new SP.FileCreationInformation();

fciNewFileFromComputer.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1020\\Desktop\\asd.txt");
```

I am able to read file but when I tried like this

```
fciNewFileFromComputer.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("u4vmebirsdev01//ReportsEBISSRS//ActiveDirectoryTest.rdl");
```

I am getting error

> Url formats are not supported

I am clueless, what to do?

Comment: Is it maybe chocking on the double-slash `//' in there and trying to interpret it as an url?

Comment: @sstn Shall I remove // by / slash ?

Comment: If that is supposed to represent a file share path (i.e. UNC), it needs a '\\\\' at the front.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this method to read file contents from a webserver (via some url)

If the file is local it will work. If it is on a network share then you should use this:

```
fciNewFileFromComputer.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\u4vmebirsdev01\ReportsEBISSRS\ActiveDirectoryTest.rdl");
```

The @ in front of the string ensures that the \ is not seen as an escape character.